# Concatenate values in sql server and group by another value | ms sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have simple select

```
select distinct  UserName, Company from Users inner join Companies on Users.UserName = Companies.UserFullName
```

The result of query looks like this:

```
  User1 | Company1
  User1 | Company2
  User1 | Company3
  User1 | Company4
  User2 | Company3
  User2 | Company6
  User2 | Company1
  User2 | Company5
```

I want to concatenate Company values and group it by User. Like this:

```
  User1 | Company1 , Company2 , Company3 , Company4
  User2 | Company3 , Company6 , Company1 , Company5
```

Is it possible thing to do in sql server?

Comment: Yes, it is. What have you tried so far, and which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to concatenate text from multiple rows into a single text string in SQL server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/how-to-concatenate-text-from-multiple-rows-into-a-single-text-string-in-sql-serv)

Comment: I'm using sql server 2014. At the moment I'm trying to use COALESCE. It works, but I can't group by correctly by User as there are still User duplicate values it query result

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use GROUP BY to concatenate strings in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273238/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server 2017, you can use the new function, `STRING_AGG`:

```
SELECT UserName,
       STRING_AGG(Company,' , ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Company) AS Companies
FROM #T1
GROUP BY Username;
```

Note that you have no ordering in your table, thus the order of `'Company3, Company6, Company1, Company5'` cannot be retained for `'User2'` unless you have some other column to order by.

Comment: Wow. If you don't mind, tell me from where can I get myself updated with new t-sql functions in 2016, 2017?

Comment: @PrabhatG Just have a [Google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=SQL+Server+2016+New+functions&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=EjqNWorvO7TS8Afb5JGgBQ). Microsoft publish documents with every edition on what's new. The first (non-Ad) result in that link is to 2016's new features.

Comment: I know that. Thought you've some blog or anything which puts up this info

Comment: @PrabhatG No, i generally just have a look at the release notes when the new editions come out; but also pay attention to the mailing lists from sites like SQL Server Central and Brent Ozar. I'm sure there are blogs out there, however, I don't have any links personally. The documentation ([What's new in Database Engine - SQL Server 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/database-engine/whats-new-in-sql-server-2017)) is quite thorough.

Answer (score 0):

The below code snippet would work for you -

```
CREATE TABLE #t1 (UserName VARCHAR(100), Company VARCHAR(100));
INSERT #t1 values ('User1','Company1');
INSERT #t1 values ('User1','Company2');
INSERT #t1 values ('User1','Company3');
INSERT #t1 values ('User1','Company4');
INSERT #t1 values ('User2','Company3');
INSERT #t1 values ('User2','Company6');
INSERT #t1 values ('User2','Company1');
INSERT #t1 values ('User2','Company5');
GO
select
    UserName,
    stuff((
        select ',' + t.[Company]
        from #t1 t
        where t.UserName = #t1.UserName
        order by t.[Company]
        for xml path('')
    ),1,1,'') as CompanyName
from #t1
group by UserName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that doesn't require the clause `FOR XML PATH`
This solution is a loop based

```
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..#t1') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #T1;
    IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..#t2') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #T2;

    CREATE TABLE #t1 (UserName VARCHAR(100), Company VARCHAR(100));
    INSERT #t1 values ('User1','Company1');
    INSERT #t1 values ('User1','Company2');
    INSERT #t1 values ('User1','Company3');
    INSERT #t1 values ('User1','Company4');
    INSERT #t1 values ('User2','Company3');
    INSERT #t1 values ('User2','Company6');
    INSERT #t1 values ('User2','Company1');
    INSERT #t1 values ('User2','Company5');
    GO

    DECLARE @Table TABLE (UserName VARCHAR(100), Combined VARCHAR(4000))
    DECLARE @i INT = 1 

    SELECT DENSE_RANK () OVER (ORDER BY UserName) Seq,  *
    INTO #T2
    FROM #t1

    WHILE @i <= (SELECT MAX(Seq) FROM #T2)
        BEGIN 
        DECLARE @ConcatedCompany VARCHAR(4000) = ''
        SELECT @ConcatedCompany+= ',' + Company
        FROM #T2
        WHERE Seq = @i

        INSERT INTO @Table (UserName , Combined)
        SELECT UserName , STUFF(@ConcatedCompany,1,1,'')
        FROM #T2
        WHERE Seq = @i
        GROUP BY UserName 

        SET @i +=1

        END

    SELECT * 
    FROM @Table
```

**UPDATE!!**

[Larnu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3484879/larnu)'s comment regarding the performance is a good point, usually I'd avoid using WHILE loops and think in terms of set based operations
so, here is the solution without a loop and without "FOR XML PATH"

```
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..#t1') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #T1
    IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..##T2') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##T2
    IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..##Table') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##Table

    CREATE TABLE #t1 (UserName VARCHAR(100), Company VARCHAR(100));
    INSERT #t1 values ('User1','Company1');
    INSERT #t1 values ('User1','Company2');
    INSERT #t1 values ('User1','Company3');
    INSERT #t1 values ('User1','Company4');
    INSERT #t1 values ('User2','Company3');
    INSERT #t1 values ('User2','Company6');
    INSERT #t1 values ('User2','Company1');
    INSERT #t1 values ('User2','Company5');
    GO

    CREATE TABLE ##Table (UserName nvarchar(50), Combined nvarchar(4000))

    SELECT DENSE_RANK () OVER (ORDER BY UserName) Seq,  *
    INTO ##T2
    FROM #t1

    DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(MAX) =''
    ;WITH T2 (Seq) AS 
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT Seq 
    FROM ##T2
    )


    SELECT @cmd += 'DECLARE @ConcatedCompany'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Seq)+' NVARCHAR(4000) = '''' 
                    SELECT @ConcatedCompany'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Seq)+' += '','' + Company FROM ##T2 WHERE Seq = '+CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Seq)+ CHAR(10)+
                    ' INSERT INTO ##Table (UserName, Combined)
                    SELECT UserName , STUFF(@ConcatedCompany'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Seq)+',1,1,'''') 
                    FROM ##T2 WHERE Seq = '+CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Seq) + CHAR(10)+
                    ' GROUP BY UserName '+CHAR(10)+
                    ';'
                    +CHAR(10)
     FROM T2


     EXEC sp_executesql  @Cmd

     SELECT UserName , Combined 
     FROM ##Table

     DROP TABLE ##Table
     DROP TABLE ##T2
```

Comment: `WHILE` loops are just inherently slow in SQL Server. A Dataset approached is by far a more efficient method.

Comment: I agree, it can also be done in a set based without the need of loop, though in small cases (small number of users) the loop is not that bad.just wanted to note that a different solution other than the "FOR XML PATH" is available to consider.